# Disable all gestures in app on Windows multi touch device (e.g. MS Surface)

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

I have PyQt test application which opens window. I use event filter to disable all gestures on MS Surface for my application. Some guestures (e.g. "Press and hold") are not recognized now, but not all.

If one finger presses the screen and you press a second finger, transparent square appears around the first finger. It looks like the system recognizes a gesture.

Can I disable ALL gesture recognition in Windows only for my application?

```
@enum.unique
class TABLET(enum.IntEnum):
    """
    @see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb969148(v=vs.85).aspx
    """
    DISABLE_PRESSANDHOLD = 0x00000001
    DISABLE_PENTAPFEEDBACK = 0x00000008
    DISABLE_PENBARRELFEEDBACK = 0x00000010
    DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEON = 0x00000100
    DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEOFF = 0x00000200
    DISABLE_TOUCHSWITCH = 0x00008000
    DISABLE_FLICKS = 0x00010000
    ENABLE_FLICKSONCONTEXT = 0x00020000
    ENABLE_FLICKLEARNINGMODE = 0x00040000
    DISABLE_SMOOTHSCROLLING = 0x00080000
    DISABLE_FLICKFALLBACKKEYS = 0x00100000
    ENABLE_MULTITOUCHDATA = 0x01000000


class EventFilter(QAbstractNativeEventFilter):

    def nativeEventFilter(self, event_type, message):
        import time
        from andy.platform.win32 import WM, MSG, TABLET

        if event_type == 'windows_generic_MSG' or event_type == 'windows_dispatcher_MSG':
            msg = ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_void_p(int(message)), ctypes.POINTER(MSG))

            if msg.contents.message == WM.TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS:
                return True, (TABLET.DISABLE_PRESSANDHOLD |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_PENTAPFEEDBACK |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_PENBARRELFEEDBACK |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEON |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEOFF |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_TOUCHSWITCH |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_FLICKS |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_SMOOTHSCROLLING |
                              TABLET.DISABLE_FLICKFALLBACKKEYS |
                              TABLET.ENABLE_MULTITOUCHDATA)

        return False, 0


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    event_filter = EventFilter()
    app.installNativeEventFilter(event_filter)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(800, 600)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Sample')
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You linked to the [solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) already. Why aren't using it?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I don't understand. How Windows Imaging Component can help me?

Comment: Wrong link, sorry. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb969148(v=vs.85).aspx) is the one that has the solution (and is right in the source code you posted).